# Show that $x$ is an "accumulation point" of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely points of $A$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,\Gamma)$ a topological Hausdorff space and $A\subset X$. Show that $x$ is an "accumulation point" of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely points of $A$.

I proved that a sequence in Hausdorff space cannot converge to more than one point, any hint thanks!

Comment: Hausdorff ($T_2$) is slight overkill. We just need that finite sets are closed, which is equivalent to $X$ being $T_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ and $U$ a neighborhood of $x$. Since $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$, by definition, there exists a point $a_0\in A\cap U$ such that $a_0$ is distinct of $x$.

Suppose constructed $a_n$ such $a_n\in U$, $a_0,...,a_n,x$ are pairwise distinct. Since $X$ is separated, there exists a neighborhood $U_n$ of $x$ such that $a_i$ is not in $U_n$ for $i=0,...,n$, $U_n\cap U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, since $A$ is a point of accumulation of $A$, there exists $a_{n+1}\in U_n\cap U\cap A$ distinct of $x$, the sequence of points $(a_n)$ is contained in $U$ and $a_i\neq a_j$ if $i\neq j$.

Suppose that every neighborhood of $x$ contains an infinite number of elements of $A$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $A$, since $A\cap U$ is infinite, there exists $a\in A\cap U$ distinct of $x$, henceforth $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

Comment: I thought there exist a little mistake in the sentence " since $A$ is a point of accumulation of $A$", regards

Answer (score 1):

First note that for any $x \in X$ we have that $\{x\}' = \emptyset$. This holds, because if $y \neq x$, we can find an open set $U$ with $y \in U$ and $x \notin U$ which means $U \cap \{x\} = \emptyset$, and $x \notin \{x\}'$. This indeed follows from Hausdorffness ($U$ can be one of the two disjoint neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$) but it is equivalent to a weaker separation axiom $T_1$.

As $(C \cup D)' = C' \cup D'$ and similarly for all finite unions, $F' = \emptyset$ for all finite subsets of $X$.

Now suppose that $x$ is an accumulation point (limit point) of $A$ but there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, where $U \cap A$ is finite.

Then $A' = ((A \cap U) \cap (A \setminus U))' = (A \cap U)' \cup (A \setminus U)' = (A \setminus U)'$, as $A \cap U$ is finite by assumption. So $x \in (A \setminus U)'$ which is a contradiction as witnessed by $U$: it is a neighbourhood of $x$ that totally misses $A \setminus U$.

So every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in an infinite set, if $x \in A'$.

The reverse is obvious.